# Wordpress Pathwell Theme Header - Remove "Send Request" button and phone number

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the Send Request image and the phone number from the right hand side of the header.
It is the pathwell theme.

If you know where to find these items in the admin tool, please let me know. I have tried all the header menus and can't find them.

The image of the header is here: I want to remove the two right hand side items.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [theme's documentation](https://pathwell.axiomthemes.com/doc/#customizer_settings_header), I don't see an option to remove those items, but you can hide them with some CSS:

```
.sc_layouts_item_link.sc_layouts_iconed_text_link,
#sc_button_1347350062 {
    display: none;
}
```

Since this is a premium theme, you can also try contacting [their support](https://themerex.net/support/).